# MacOS running jar from Applications/app.app ends with incorrect path error during loading .fxml

Tags: java, macos, .app, javapackager

I have created an java application that i would like to convert to MacOS .app. I managed to run java packager against my jar file, which created .pkg file for me. After installation app is starting (preloader) but it end with `.fxml` file load problem due to '!' char that is added for some reason to path:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/Applications/app.app/Contents/Java/app.jar!/programGUI.fxml
```

Jar file is working fine when is located on other location that `/Applications/app.app/`.
I already tried to start it manually from `Application/app.app/Contents/Java/` and `Application/app.app/Contents/MacOS/`, but result was the same (even with sudo).
I tired to change permissions (chmod) plus system preferences (`system preferences > privacy`) but still no luck.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/programGUI.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
```

Worth to mention that in similar way I am loading background picture for preloader and it is working.

```
Image backgroundImage = new Image(classLoader.getResource("splashScreen.png").toString());
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Edit: Adding Main Class as requested

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private BooleanProperty ready = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            myStart();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        ready.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            public void changed(
                    ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1) {
                if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(t1)) {
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
                                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                                loader.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
                                loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/programGUI.fxml"));
                                Parent root = loader.load();
                                Scene scene = new Scene(root, 900, 600);
                                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                                primaryStage.setTitle("myName");
                                primaryStage.setResizable(false);
                                primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(classLoader.getResource("icon.png").toString()));
                                primaryStage.show();
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private void myStart() throws Exception {
        Task task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
            FileDownloader fd = new FileDownloader(new URL("www.example.com/myfile.txt"));
                while (fd.status == 0) { //0 = downloading, 2 = completed
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                        if (fd.getProgress() > 0) {
                            notifyPreloader(new Preloader.ProgressNotification((fd.getProgress())));
                        }
                        if (fd.status == 100) {
                            ready.setValue(Boolean.TRUE);
                            notifyPreloader(new Preloader.StateChangeNotification(
                                    Preloader.StateChangeNotification.Type.BEFORE_START));
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        Thread t = new Thread(task);
        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Main.class, myPreloader.class, args);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Piotr

Comment: Hi, can you post the class main please?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo added to 1st post

Comment: Thanks, I have to need more information, an example the structure of the project, if you used some construction system (ant maven or gradle)

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo I am not using any of it. Just straight forward javaFX project.

Comment: a question for you, because javapackager generated a pkg and not an .app? is your configuration?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo I managed to fix the issue. It was caused by .fxml controler. For some reason i did not get any details why javafx.fxml.LoadException happen and i assumed that it was connected with the location.
After I cleared all onAction properties and renamed all objects that I was calling from controller class problem was resolved.
Nevertheless thanks for your effort vincenzopalazzo